# Access phpmyadmin remotely

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, remote-access

I want to make this computer as my server for my office. i've searched the internet on how to access phpmyadmin remotly and some suggest to edit the `config.inc.php` to add this

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = 'hostname/Ip Adress';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'username';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'password';
```

some suggest to edit the `httpd-xampp.conf` and change some code with this

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

which one should i use? i don't want it to be allow from all so not everyone can access it since it's for office.
i'm using Windows 10 and PHP 7.3.2

Comment: Do you have static ip in your office?

Comment: You just need routing stuff in your router. Nothing else.

Comment: not yet but i’m gonna do it... so which one should i do? the httpd-xampp.conf or comfig.inc.php?

Comment: Use virtual host in you xampp conf. If you can visit you phpmyadmin from local network you can configure to make it public from router.

Comment: If you dont have static ip address, your public ip address is dynamic it keeps changing, its a lot pain to keep track of it.

Comment: Can i access phpmyadmin from other computer if i use virtual host?

Comment: Normally how you accessing your phpmyadmin from your computer?

Comment: Enter the server ip address on client url and then the project

Comment: You can access from that ip address from another computer in same network, for outside use, route to your computer ip address in router settings.

Comment: firefox can't open my virtual host it said it's not secured...